# Appear conditionalPanel after pressing the reset button on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Friends, could you help me with the following problem:
The executable code is working correctly. I am using the database via fileInput. It's working. I insert the functionality of when I inserted the database the conditionalPanel appears. So far it's ok. My problem is that when I press the reset button and insert the database again, conditionalPanel no longer appears.  I think there must be something on the server reset button.  Can you help me?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                                                                                                                                 + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  if (Filter1==2){
    Q1<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25)) 
    Q3<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.75))
    L<-Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    S<-Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    df_1<-subset(df,Waste>L[1]) 
    df<-subset(df_1,Waste<S[1])
  }

  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 


  #Number of clusters
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Localization
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)

  #Scatter Plot
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
  g<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4)
  Centro_View<- g +  geom_text(data=df, mapping=aes(x=eval(Longitude), y=eval(Latitude), label=Waste), size=3, hjust=-0.1)+ geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes(Longitude, Latitude), color= "green", size=4) + geom_text(data=df1, mapping = aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, label = 1:k), color = "black", size = 4)
  plotGD<-print(Centro_View + ggtitle("Scatter Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))

  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 

             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Import excel")), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          radioButtons("filtro1", h3("Select properties"),
                                       choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                                      "Exclude properties" = 2),
                                       selected = 1),

                          tags$b(h5("(a) Choose other filters")),
                          tags$b(h5("(b) Choose clusters")),  
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 8, value = 5),

                          conditionalPanel(
                            "output.fileUploaded == true",
                            tags$p(h3("Are you satisfied?")),
                          tags$b(h5("(a) Choose others filters")),
                          tags$b(h5("(b) Choose number of clusters"))),  
                          actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                        ),

                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))

                      ))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
  })


  Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider,1,1)
  }
  })


  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$df <- NULL
    updateRadioButtons(session,"Slider", selected = 5)
    output$fileUploaded <-NULL
  })

  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    !is.null(input$data)
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)

  Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider,1,1)
  }
  })


  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[2]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$Slider,{
    updateSelectInput(session,'select',
                      choices=unique(df[df==input$Slider]))
  }) 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal, but something you can try. This is a smaller (reproducible) example to test. Your question might get more attention if it is reduced to what is needed to reproduce the problem.

You can add another `reactiveValues` flag (in this case called `clear`) that tracks whether data has been loaded or not, and use that.

I looked around for good solutions on resetting `fileInput` but found mostly work arounds. In this case, when you hit `reset`, the `fileInput` still looks the same, which is not desirable.

However, when you hit `reset` the `conditionalPanel` should be response through `output$fileUploaded`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readxl)

df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), 
                   Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), 
                   Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), 
                   Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), 
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Import excel")), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          radioButtons("filtro1", h3("Select properties"),
                                       choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                                      "Exclude properties" = 2),
                                       selected = 1),

                          tags$b(h5("(a) Choose other filters")),
                          tags$b(h5("(b) Choose clusters")),  
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 8, value = 5),
                          conditionalPanel(
                            "output.fileUploaded == true",
                            tags$p(h3("Are you satisfied?")),
                            tags$b(h5("(a) Choose others filters")),
                            tags$b(h5("(b) Choose number of clusters"))),  
                          actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL, clear = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$df <- NULL
    v$clear <- FALSE
    updateRadioButtons(session, "Slider", selected = 5)
  })

  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
    v$clear <- TRUE
  })

  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    v$clear
  })

  outputOptions(output, "fileUploaded", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, 'select', choices=unique(df[df==input$Slider]))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It worked Ben, I don't even know how to thank =). I was looking at several sources, but I didn't find anything related to my problem, because it was working, it only gave an error when I pressed reset and I tried to load the file again. But now it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Ben, hope you're alright! Could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490301/adjust-shiny-code-to-generate-correct-graph-depending-on-the-date-code-you-choos

Answer (score 0):

When the reset button is pressed, you set `output$fileUploaded <-NULL`, and the condition to show the panel `conditionalPanel("output.fileUploaded == true",` is not met anymore.

You can possibly change the condition to `conditionalPanel("output.fileUploaded == true | output.fileUploaded == NULL",`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it the way you told me by changing the condition to `` `conditionalPanel (" output.fileUploaded == true | output.fileUploaded == NULL ",` `However, now it is showing all the text regarding the condition. is it necessary to change something on the server too?

Comment: maybe keep the code as it was but remove `output$fileUploaded <-NULL`?

Comment: So friend from what I noticed when I left the condition as you commented: `` `conditionalPanel (" output.fileUploaded == true | output.fileUploaded == NULL "` `'' in the UI, it always shows the descriptive text when starting shiny.

Comment: That way ```conditionalPanel (" output.fileUploaded == true``` that I had done it does not appear when starting shiny.

Comment: am I missing something?